# Is there a sample GAS code for interacting with Heroku API?

Tags: heroku, google-apps-script

I need to change Heroku config vars programatically from an apps script.

I have the Heroku Platform API Reference, including info on OAuth, but I'm not experienced enough to use these to write the Google Apps Script code from scratch and a sample implementation would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+heroku)?

Comment: I tried. None of them seem to be helpful. (Also tried Googling in general -- also no luck.) https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/tree/master/samples had potential but doesn't include sample for Heroku)

Comment: So try and create one  using those samples as a exercise  and ask a question if you hit a stumbling block, that you aren't able to solve.

Comment: "[Questions asking us to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"

Comment: IMHO the question wasn't for a _subjective_ recommendation of the kind that tends to attract _opinionated_answers_. Perhaps it was overly vague, because 2 weeks ago I didn't have the knowledge to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily it wasn't as complicated as it originally appeared -- in a good part, because OAuth wasn't necessary, just an API KEY from Heroku on their [Manage Account](https://dashboard.heroku.com/account) page.

```
HEROKU_ADDRESS = 'https://api.heroku.com/apps';

function getApps() {
  // Get all apps of Bearer, including their IDs and names. Either ID or name can be used later on as APP_ID.
  var options = {
    'method' : 'get',
    'headers' : {
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ HEROKU_API_KEY
    },
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(HEROKU_ADDRESS, options);  
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function getConfigVars() {
  // Get all config-vars of App
  var options = {
    'method' : 'get',
    'headers' : {
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ HEROKU_API_KEY
    },
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(HEROKU_ADDRESS+'/' + APP_ID +'/config-vars', options);  
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function updateConfigVars(newConfigVars) {
  // Set/Update some config-vars of App
  // returns all config-vars
  var options = {
    'method' : 'patch',
    'headers' : {
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ HEROKU_API_KEY,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'payload': JSON.stringify(newConfigVars)
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(HEROKU_ADDRESS+'/' + APP_ID +'/config-vars', options);  
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function delConfigVar(ConfigVarName) {
  // Delete a config-var of App (set to null)
  // returns all remaining config-vars
  var ConfigVar2del = {};
  ConfigVar2del[ConfigVarName] = null;
  var options = {
    'method' : 'patch',
    'headers' : {
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ HEROKU_API_KEY,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'payload': JSON.stringify(ConfigVar2del)
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(HEROKU_ADDRESS+'/' + APP_ID +'/config-vars', options);  
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function del() {
  delConfigVar('name');
}

function update() {
  var newConfigVars = {
    'name': 'some value',
    'test': 770
  };
  updateConfigVars(newConfigVars);
}
```

With these functions one can get info on all of Bearer's Heroku apps, including their names and IDs that can be subsequently used to get all config vars of the app, or modify/delete some of those config vars.